# A simple JavaScript function that does prime factorization

Tags: javascript, beginner, programming-challenge, node.js, primes

This is a simple JavaScript function that does prime factorization.

I wrote it on an Android phone with online editor (I don't have access to computers in night time):

[image]

Code:

```javascript
function factorize(n) {
  if (!(Number.isInteger(n) && n >= 2)) {
    throw 'Input is invalid'
  }
  const factors = []
  while (n % 2 == 0) {
    factors.push(2)
    n /= 2
  }
  for (let i=3; i<=Math.round(Math.sqrt(n)+1); i+=2) {
    while (n % i == 0) {
      factors.push(i)
      n /= i
    }
  }
  if (n > 1) {
    factors.push(n)
  }
  return factors
}

console.log(factorize(31556952))
```

Output

```
> Array [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 773]
```

The test number is the number of seconds in a Gregorian year.

How can it be improved?

Comment: I don't know JavaScript. But how  does it handle division /. Is this an integer division or is this a floating point division? If it is floating point, can there occur rounding errors if you have a large n and do a lot of divisions? Usually one uses integer arithmetic for such calculations

Answer (score 1):

Taking a square root is a very slow operation, so it's a bad idea to do it for every iteration of the loop. Rather, you should only update the limit whenever `n` changes.

Comment: Or use `i*i<=n`.

Comment: @Teepeemm But you have still a lot of integer multiplications that are not needed if you calculate the root before the loop.